# I want to read and write both from server but not at the same time

Tags: java, sockets

I have a server class which has a main method that is using a while(true) to keep the server running. I have the code for both reading and writing the data in the while loop. I have a client class which has 3 methods, first one read the data and second and third one write the data. I have another class called display controller that is calling the methods in the client class depending on what we are doing in the application.

```
public class Server {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(666);
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("MYJSON.json");
    BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    while (true) {
      Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

  /*   InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new 
      InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
      BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
      String str = bufferedReader.readLine();
      writeJson(str); */

      String str;
      OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new
      OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
      PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(outputStreamWriter);
      str = buff.readLine();
      printWriter.write(str);
      printWriter.flush();
      printWriter.close();

      InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new 
      InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
      BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
      String str1 = bufferedReader.readLine();
      if (str1.equals("createNewJson")) {
        fileReader = new FileReader("MYJSON.json");
      }

    }
  }

import java.io.*;

    import java.net.Socket;

    public class Client{

    public static String readDataFromServer() throws IOException{
    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",666);
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new 
    InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
    System.out.println();
    String str = bufferedReader.readLine();
    System.out.println(str);
    return str;

    }

    public static void createNewJsonFile() throws IOException {
      Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",666);
      OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new 
      OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
      PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(outputStreamWriter);
      printWriter.write("CreateNewJson");
    }

      public static void writeDataToServer(String str) throws IOException {
       Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",666);

        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new 
        OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(outputStreamWriter);
        printWriter.write(str);
        printWriter.flush();
        printWriter.close();

        }


    }
```

The problem is when the read method is called in the client class, the server is executing the code in the while loop to send the data to the server but it also executing the code for reading the data from the client but the client is not sending any data as write method in the client class is not being called. I don't want it. So, when it executes the code to read the data, I am getting connection reset error. I know it is because my server is unnecessarily executing the lines of code in the while loop that reads the data even though client is not sending any data to server to read. Is there anyway I can resolve this issue?